# How can I get the name of a variable type, when it's stored as String or Boolean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, mongoose, types

Mongoose has you input field types as `String`, `Boolean`, `Number`, etc., which are functions. I want to read these values as a string, so I can use them as object keys. How can I get 'String' from string, 'Boolean' from Boolean?

```
var Model = {
    name: String,
    likes: Number
};

console.log('the type of name is '+Model.name)
```

this will of course print out something like:

```
the type of name is function String() {
    [native code]
}
```

as what I'm referencing is a function

Comment: `typeof Model.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function objects have a [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), which returns the name of the function as a string.

```js
for(const fn of [
  String,           //"String"
  Boolean,          //"Boolean"
  Number,           //"Number"
  function foo(){}, //"foo"
  class bar{},      //"bar"
  () => {},         //""
  new Function(""), //"anonymous"
]) console.log(fn.name)
```

In your case, as `model.name` is a function, you can retrieve its name by `model.name.name`:

```js
var Model = {
    name: String,
    likes: Number
};

console.log(Model.name.name)  //String
console.log(Model.likes.name) //Number
```